# I hate hats!​​​

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I hate hats. I got a hat today (00.01 hours). I haven't done anything wrong! Nothing at all, at least here on the not-so-dark-side on ELL (as opposed to EL&U). Why am I being given hats!? Hats is bad. I'm an santaethist and celebrating Santashness is not what I want. And I hate headgear. An for that reason,  I've been avoiding ELL like the plague. *Why* did I get a hat? Boo to hats.

Now I've been given one, I don't know if I can not wear it or not (I mean within myself, not within the "ELL rules").

Why was I given a hat?

I want an answer.

Comment: I don't hate Christmas, but I do hate hats. If you wants to know why, ask my girl fiend (sic), and have a look at my bank account.

Comment: Why did you get a hat? For the same reason my daughter got her Participation trophy.

Comment: *Cucullus non facit monachum*.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't speak French ...

Comment: So, you're, what, +1/-1 away from getting a new hat for this? :P

Answer (score 9):

If you really hate hats, you can always click ***I hate hats*** in the Winter Bash drop-down:

> [image]

Until you do that, I'm afraid the system will assume **you love hats** and keep giving you hats based on this misapprehension.

Comment: I can put up with the system assuming I like hats - but being given one before I've actually earned one!!! - That's completely beyond the snale!

Comment: The hat you got says 'ask, answer, or vote on December 14th'.  I think that they might award it for votes before and after that 24-hour period too, because people might be in other time zones and they don't want them to miss out on hats.  So the system probably feels you've earned it!

Comment: Well, I suppose that's an answer. Even if it's a bit escargotish. Harrumph.

Comment: @snailboat - I must say, that doughnut looks dapper on your gastropod. Long live hats!

Comment: @Araucaria SE sites run on UTC, hats run on UTC. So what may be the 13th for you is the 14th in UTC time. It's the same for me. The UTC day rolls over at 4-5 my time.